# Chrome blicking cursor

Tags: google-chrome

I don't know if this is a common issue, but some times ago I started to see a blinking cursor onthe Chrome's webpages, like it was in "edit" mode...

[image]

probably is due to an extension that I would install, but now, I don't know how to get rid of this.

Wherever I click I leave the cursor blinking at that place....

[image]

I have not so much extensions actually, but I have unsinstalled some

[image]

Comment: Did you close Chrome after you uninstalled the extensions, and reopened?

Comment: yes, multiple times I closed an reopened Chrome after the uninstall of those

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is often called [caret browsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_navigation) and is used to allow you to select text without using a mouse.

Press <kbd>F7</kbd> to enable or disable this mode in Chrome (as well as Firefox, Edge, MSIE).

- Accessibility on Chrome > [Use a text cursor to navigate & select text](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/10129654)
- Accessibility features in Firefox > [Using a keyboard to navigate within webpages](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/accessibility-features-firefox-make-firefox-and-we#w_using-a-keyboard-to-navigate-within-webpages)

Most browsers (and other kinds of document viewers) have this feature available, typically somewhere under "Accessibility settings".

[image: Screenshot of the option under Chrome's "Accessibility" section]

Comment: Oh wow, this is actually useful. :) Thanks.

Comment: no idea how did I activate it, probably via F7 shortcut by inattention....