# Remove cursor from pdf

Tags: pdf, cursor

I open my PDFs with MS Edge. 2 days ago my cat got on my keyboard & since then there's this cursor showing on every PDF I open. I cannot remove it and scrolling the pages are quite annoying with this cursor being there. I searched online for help but couldn't find any helpful article. Could anyone help me on how I can remove this cursor permanently?

I have tried to highlight the cursed Cursor in the attached screenshot. [image: I have highlighted the cursor here]

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of the issue by editing your question

Comment: Does https://superuser.com/q/1615958 answer the question?

Comment: @user1686 yes, thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome blicking cursor](https://superuser.com/questions/1615958/chrome-blicking-cursor)

Answer (score 1):

This is called caret mode
It allow you to select text with keyboard
**Just press F7 to switch between**
[caret mode turn off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0wiy.png)