# Blinking cursor on weird places with Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, cursor

I'm seeing a blinking cursors on weird places on Chrome: on the top left of a video on YouTube, on Instagram, even on this site.

[image: Blinking cursor on YT]
[image: Binking cursor on SuperUser]

How to prevent that?

Comment: Thanks for letting us know.

Comment: I assume the question is obviously how to get rid of it, but remember to ask a specific question with `?` on this network, always. Does it happen in incognito mode? What extensions are you using?

Answer (score 1):

From [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1615970/598567):

This is often called [caret browsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_navigation) and is used to allow you to select text without using a mouse.

Press <kbd>F7</kbd> to enable or disable this mode in Chrome (as well as Firefox, Edge, MSIE).

- Accessibility on Chrome > [Use a text cursor to navigate & select text](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/10129654)
- List item
- Accessibility features in Firefox > [Using a keyboard to navigate within webpages](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/accessibility-features-firefox-make-firefox-and-we#w_using-a-keyboard-to-navigate-within-webpages)

Most browsers (and other kinds of document viewers) have this feature available, typically somewhere under "Accessibility settings".

[image: Screenshot of the option under Chrome's "Accessibility" section]

If this solves your issue, please upvote the original answer posted in the link at the top of this answer.